# Why does UNIX `shred` command rename files to 000, then 00, then 0 before deleting?

Tags: deletion

I was using `shred` to get rid of some files and I noticed that it did the following:

```
shred: 0000: renamed to 000
shred: 000: renamed to 00
shred: 00: renamed to 0
```

Does anyone know what's the point in renaming file to 000... etc?

Comment: Have you Googled this? "shred: 0000: renamed to 000" returns a lot of results explaining why they do it.

Comment: @schroeder Including this very question as #1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After shred has finished overwriting the data of your file, (and assuming you used the -u flag to remove the file) it renames the file multiple times in order to also overwrite the filesystem record, removing metadata and all traces that the file existed.

Of course the success of the shred command depends on filesystem implementation, some newer journaling filesystems do not overwrite data in place; see [details here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/shred)